# Adding a class to elements depending on their length

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to loop through elements and check their length, then add a class if parents have more than 2 elements.

Now the class is been added to all parent elements.

My code is like this:

```js
let CheckOptions = [...document.querySelectorAll(".value select option")]
let checkSelects = [...document.querySelectorAll(".value select")]


checkSelects.forEach(checkSelect => {
  if(CheckOptions.length >= 2){
    CheckOptions.forEach(checkSelects => checkSelect.classList.add("active"));
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
```

```html
<div class="value">
    <select class="select">
        <option class="option">1</option>
        <option class="option">2</option>
        <option class="option">3</option>
        <option class="option">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="value">
    <select class="select">
        <option class="option">1</option>
        <option class="option">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="value">
    <select class="select">
        <option class="option">1</option>
        <option class="option">2</option>
        <option class="option">3</option>
        <option class="option">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `CheckOptions.length` this is the length of all the options in the document, not per select.

Comment: In `.forEach(checkSelects =>`…`)`, you never use this `checkSelects` variable. `CheckOptions` is the list of all 10 options. You probably want `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".value select")).forEach((select) => { if(select.length >= 2){ select.classList.add("active"); } });`

Comment: also all the selects you show have `options >= 2`

Comment: Wait, do you mean _“more than 2 elements”_ or _`>= 2`_? Which one is it?

Comment: Yes, you are guys right, I meant `> 2` not `>=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access a `select`'s `options` by the `options` select property so we check the length of that property's value is greater than 2, if so, we add the class `active` to the current `select`.

Try the following `.js` code:

```
let checkSelects = [...document.querySelectorAll(".value select")]

checkSelects.forEach(checkSelect => {
  const options = checkSelect.options
  if (options.length > 2) {
    checkSelect.classList.add("active")
  }
})
```

Also, in order to get the `length`, instead of getting the `options` property of the `checkSelect`, you can just get the `length` by `checkSelect.length` property.

So it would be:

```
let checkSelects = [...document.querySelectorAll(".value select")]

checkSelects.forEach(checkSelect => {
  if (checkSelect.length > 2) {
    checkSelect.classList.add("active")
  }
})
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the answer and for guiding me to understand this better.

Comment: It is a pleasure to have helped you.